# How to replace array values with another arrays values in Angular8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

I have two sample data named **oldArray** and **newArray**.

I want to replace oldArray objects with newArray objects if makeLineName and makeProcessTypeId of both oldArray and
newArray is same.

**For Ex -** In oldArray, we have TestDemo1 and Test565 makeLineName available  and same
TestDemo1 and Test565 makeLineName available in newArray also,
So i want to search newArray for this TestDemo1 and Test565 makeLineName
and if same makeLineName availalble in newArray than replace the fields values of
oldArray makelinename with same makelinename object of newarray.

and if same makelinename is not available in newArray, then oldArray object which not matched than it will
remain as it is.

```
oldArray = [
      {       
        makeLineName: "TestDemo1",
        avtBCT: 80,
        MaxBCT: 80
      },
      {      
        makeLineName: "Test565",
        avtBCT: '',
        MaxBCT: ''
      },
      {      
        makeLineName: "Luck", 
        avtBCT: 60,
        MaxBCT: 60
      }
    ];

    const newArray = [
      {       
        makeLineName: "TestDemo1",
        avtBCT: 500,
        MaxBCT: 500
      },
      {      
        makeLineName: "Test565",
        avtBCT: 600,
        MaxBCT: 600
      }
    ];
```

**Expected Output =**

```
 filteredData = [
      {       
        makeLineName: "TestDemo1",
        avtBCT: 500,
        MaxBCT: 500
      },
      {      
        makeLineName: "Test565",
        avtBCT: 600,
        MaxBCT: 600
      },
      {      
        makeLineName: "Luck", 
        avtBCT: 60,
        MaxBCT: 60
      }
    ];
```

Comment: what if `newArray` has extra elements, those aren't exist in `oldArray`?

Comment: @PankajParkar, This situation will not come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this line of code :

```
let resultArray = oldArray.map(el => newArray.find(f => f.makeLineName == el.makeLineName) ?? el);
```

to solve you error try :

```
let resultArray = oldArray.map(el =>  {
    let newElement = newArray.find(f => f.makeLineName == el.makeLineName);
    return newElement ? newElement : el;
});
```

Comment: Your ?? is showing error error TS1005: ':' expected.

Comment: Try the second piece of please